# Upgraded to PHP 5.5 on mac - having to load PATH into terminal each time

Tags: php, macos

Last night I upgraded to PHP 5.5.3 using http://php-osx.liip.ch/ on my new Macbook.  I have OS X v10.8.5

Each time on launch terminal or iTerm, I have to put PATH=/usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH into the terminal to get it to properly set the path.  Why?

I did put the same path into ~/.bash_profile and ~/.profile.

Running phpinfo in the browser, without touching terminal, does show PHP 5.5.3.

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal and type:

```
curl -s http://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 5.5
```

5.5 is a PHP version (if you want install a specific version), then check if it works:

```
php -v
```

Answer (score -1):

In `~/.bash_profile` add `export PATH=/usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH`

My `~/.profile` is currently empty.

Now in terminal do

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Try `php -v`.

I've restarted terminal a few times with the correct results. Both `phpinfo()` and terminal `php -v` show PHP 5.5.4.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You're flailing. Removing `/usr/bin` from PATH would break almost everything *except* PHP, and restarting Apache would certainly not have any effect.